# How to know when a certain sequence of chars is typed?

Tags: python, tkinter, key-bindings

I'm writing an angry-birds-like game, and I want that when the player types 'g', and then 'o', and then 'd' ('god', for 'god mode'), a target will apear on the spot that the bird will currently (given the degrees and initial velocity) land on (if you'd fire it). - god mode is available 3 times in a game.

So I tried class, and storing each two-last chars typed:
[I use tkinter and Image, ImageTk from PIL]

```
class GodMode:

times_left = 3   # Default

def __init__(self, master, image_file):
    self.master = master
    self.target_image = Image.open(image_file) 
    self.target = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.target_image.resize((RED_CROSS_WIDTH, RED_CROSS_HEIGHT), Image.ANTIALIAS))

def display(self, bird):
    self.times_left -= 1
    self.x = physics.distance_traveled(bird)
    self.y = TARGET_Y_LOCATION
    self.master.create_image(self.x, self.y, image = self.target)

def typing_god(self, keystroke, bird):
    '''This function is first called when "g" is typed, from another 
    function (who is binded in the "main" function)
    '''
    if keystroke is None:
        self.last_char = "g"
    else:
        if keystroke.char == "d" or keystroke.char == "D":
            if self.last_char == "o" and self.char_before_last == "g":
                if self.times_left == 3:
                    self.god_mode_start(bird)
                elif 0 < self.times_left:
                    self.god_mode_alert(bird)
                else:
                    help_over()
                    return
        else:
            self.char_before_last = self.last_char
            self.last_char = keystroke.char
    self.master.bind('<Key>', lambda event: typing_god(event, bird))

def god_mode_start(self):
    start_input = messagebox.askyesno(title = "GOD Mode", message = "The god mode is only optional 3 times. Are you sure?")
    if not start_input:
        return
    self.display(bird)

def god_mode_alert(self, bird):
    start = messagebox.showinfinfo(title = "GOD Mode", message = GOD_MODE_FORMAT % self.gode_mode_left)
    if not start:
        return
    self.display(bird)

@staticmethod
def help_over():
    messagebox.showinfo(title = "GOD Mode not available", message = "You have used all your help.")
```

...but that didn't work, I can't tell why.

Thanks a lot for any help!

David

Comment: But what is the error exactly?

Comment: No error, it simply doesn't work. A target does not apear in the place the bird would have land if you'd fired it.

Comment: `self.master.bind('<Key>', lambda event: typing_god(event, bird))` that looks suspicious - are you trying to call `typing_god` from within `GodMode` class? If so, then you should change it to `self.typing_god`

Comment: You're right. I changed it, but it still didn't work.

Comment: For extra challenge, write a solution that also works for cheat codes "XYZZY" and "idspispopd", and doesn't use a variable named `char_before_char_before_char_before_char_before_char_before_char_before_char_before_char_before_char_before_last`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) for that. You can set the `maxlen = 3`. And you can append to it when you get a new keystroke. Checking if you have `god` in the `deque` is also easy:

```
In [1]: from collections import deque
In [2]: d = deque(maxlen=3)
In [3]: d.append('g') # new keystroke
In [4]: d.append('o') # new keystroke
In [5]: d.append('d') # new keystroke
In [6]: d
Out[6]: deque(['g', 'o', 'd'], maxlen=3)
In [7]: ''.join(d) == 'god'  # check if we already in the god mode
Out[7]: True
In [8]: d.append('x') # new keystroke
In [9]: d
Out[9]: deque(['o', 'd', 'x'], maxlen=3)
In [10]: ''.join(d) == 'god' # check if we already in the god mode
Out[10]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `self.master.bind('<Key>', lambda event: typing_god(event, bird))` may never be getting called, have you added a print around this statement to check?

You may want to instead put it in the constructor, and use `self.typing_god`:

```
def __init__(self, master, image_file):
    self.master = master
    self.target_image = Image.open(image_file) 
    self.target = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.target_image.resize((RED_CROSS_WIDTH, RED_CROSS_HEIGHT), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    # Add a debug statement to check that this method is getting called
    print "Binding key events to self.typing_god"
    # Bind the key down event in the constructor
    self.master.bind('<Key>', lambda event: self.typing_god(event, bird))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can string events together when doing a bind. So, for example, you can bind on the three character sequence "god" (eg: `"<g><o><d>"`)

```
def god_mode(event):
    print("god mode is activated")
some_widget.bind("<g><o><d>", god_mode)
```

Assuming that `some_widget` has keyboard focus, when you press the keys "g", "o" and "d" in that order, the message will print.

This is a good opportunity to use virtual events. You can define your own event and bind to it instead:

```
some_widget.event_add("<<GodMode>>", "<g><o><d>")
some_widget.bind("<<GodMode>>", god_mode)
```